# Flex and Bison on Mac OS X Lion with Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: c, compiler-construction, xcode4.3, flex-lexer

I want to develop my own C compiler to get deeper into flex and bison for my compiler lessons at University, but I can't find flex and bison, which I've seen described in some other posts. Do I need to install extra packages for Xcode or is there any other way?

I'm running Mac OS X Lion and have Xcode 4.3.2.

Comment: Should this be tagged by Adobe Flex?  Or is gnu-flex more appropriate?

Comment: Tagged as gnu-flex now. Thanks for the little hint!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Flex* and *bison* are also included with the optional Command-Line Tools download for Xcode 4.3. See instructions at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html on how to install this. They end up installed in /usr/bin.

You may prefer getting them via port as trojanfoe suggested, since this gets you newer versions.

Answer (score 4):

Install [macports](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://www.macports.org/&ei=GFWdT-zKJuGm0QXRn_iBDw&usg=AFQjCNFPVXqLbZ-ONSRu47qlQ2iCK6CaLg) and do:

```
$ sudo port install flex bison
```

<strike>However you might need to *rig-up* the `/Developer` directory using a symbolic link first:</strike>

```
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer /Developer
```

(There is no longer any need to *rig-up* anything).

Comment: The same can be done with homebrew; `brew install flex bison`